# Power BI reports / WebView in Xamarin Forms - Error & crash ([AUX]GuiExtAuxCheckAuxPath:635: Null anb)

Tags: javascript, c#, xamarin, webview, powerbi

I'm experiencing some issues, and I'm not exactly sure what's causing them. The thing is, I have a WebView where I load a string that's forming an HTML. Within this HTML, I'm using JavaScript to generate a Power BI report, and it's working perfectly. However, **every time I interact with the HTML in the WebView**, I see a message in the console output, which is as follows:

```
[GPUAUX] [AUX]GuiExtAuxCheckAuxPath:635: Null anb
```

Also, I'm seeing these other messages when I perform any **interaction with the Power BI report inside the HTML**. In other words, if the report has a scroll, and I scroll up and down in the report view, the console output gets filled with these messages.
I'm also seeing other messages that vary between **"1 line", "7 lines", "14 lines", etc:**

```
[chatty] uid=10261(xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx) RenderThread identical 1 line
[chatty] uid=10261(xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx) RenderThread identical 35 lines
```

The issue is that the Power BI report I'm displaying in the WebView has multiple views, and I'm creating buttons to switch between those views. I'm doing this because, when developing for mobile, the layoutType: 2 doesn't display all the report views properly. So, I create buttons dynamically for each view, and I use them to switch between the views.

The other problem, in addition to the console messages, is that after some time of viewing reports and switching between views, the app simply crashes. I'm not sure why this is happening either. Here's what the console output looks like at the time of the crash:

```
[cr_ChildProcessConn] onServiceDisconnected (crash or killed by oom): pid=5082 bindings:W S
[chromium] [ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(149)] Renderer process (5082) crash detected (code 5).
[chromium] [FATAL:crashpad_client_linux.cc(667)] Render process (5082)'s crash wasn't handled by all associated webviews, triggering application crash.
[libc] Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 4549 (rig.xxxxxxxxxxx), pid 4549 (rig.(nameOfProject))
```

**This is how I'm generating the Power BI report in an HTML format, which I later load into a WebView. (In C#)**

```
var html = $@"
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Add references to powerbi-client scripts -->
    <script src=""https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/powerbi-client/2.22.3/powerbi.js""></script>
    <!-- Add CSS for organizing buttons in a grid and the title -->
    <style>
        #contenedorPrincipal {{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }}
        #titulo {{
            font-size: 18px;
            margin: 10px;
            font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
        }}
        #embedContainer {{
            width: 100%;
            height: 550px;
        }}
        #botones {{
            display: flex;
            overflow-x: auto;
        }}
        button {{
            flex: 0 0 auto;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 16px;
        }}
        #paginaActual {{
            font-size: 14px;
            margin: 10px;
            font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
        }}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Main container including title and report container -->
    <div id=""contenedorPrincipal"">
        <!-- Title -->
        <div id=""titulo"">{dashboardTitle}</div>
        <!-- Element to display the current page -->
        <div id=""paginaActual""><span id=""paginaActualNombre""></span></div>
        <!-- Container for the Power BI report -->
        <div id=""embedContainer""></div>
        <!-- Buttons container -->
        <div id=""botones""></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        // Function to update the current page
        function updatePaginaActual(pagina) {{
            document.getElementById('paginaActualNombre').innerText = pagina;
        }}

        // Configure and load the Power BI report
        var config = {{
            type: 'report',
            embedUrl: '{embedUrl}',
            settings: {{
                layoutType: {intLayoutType},
                navContentPaneEnabled: true,
                panes: {{
                    pageNavigation: {{
                        visible: true,
                        position: 1
                    }},
                }},
                filterPaneEnabled: false,
                filters: {{ visible: false }}
            }},
            filters: {hasFilter} ? {filter} : null,
            accessToken: '{accessToken}'
        }};
        var embedContainer = document.getElementById('embedContainer');
        var report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, config);
        report.on('loaded', () => {{
            console.log('Loaded');
            report.getPages().then((pages) => {{
                const filtered = pages.filter(page => {{
                    if (page.visibility === 0) {{
                        return page;
                    }}
                }}).map(page => ({{ name: page.displayName, linkurl: `https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=${{page.report.config.id}}&groupId={workspaceId}&pageName=${{page.name}}` }}))
                var botones = document.getElementById('botones');
                for (let i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {{
                    var boton = document.createElement('button');
                    boton.innerHTML = filtered[i].name;
                    boton.addEventListener('click', async () => {{
                        try {{
                            console.log(filtered[i].name);
                            powerbi.reset(embedContainer);
                            config.embedUrl = filtered[i].linkurl;
                            var report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, config);
                            console.log('Página cambiada con éxito');
                            // Update the current page when clicking a button
                            updatePaginaActual(filtered[i].name);
                        }} catch (error) {{
                            console.error('Error al cambiar la página:', error);
                        }}
                    }});
                    botones.appendChild(boton);
                }}
                console.log(filtered);
                // Initially, display the first page in the current page element
                updatePaginaActual(filtered[0].name);
            }})
        }})
        console.log(report);
        console.log('AccessToken: ' + config.accessToken);
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {{
            console.log('La página se ha cargado completamente.');
        }});
    </script>
</body>
</html>";


 // Load the HTML into the WebView asynchronously
 powerBIWebView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource { Html = html };
```

Any way to solve these issues? I think the first part of the problem, which is the error message, is related to the WebView, and the other part of the problem, which is the crashing, has to do with switching views, but I'm not sure.

If you need more information, I'd be happy to provide it.
Greetings, and thank you very much for your help.